# Creating a TypedDict with enum keys

Tags: python, enums, type-hinting, python-typing, typeddict

I am trying to create a `TypedDict` for better code completion and am running into an issue.

I want to have a fixed set of keys (an Enum) and the values to match a specific list of objects depending on the key.

For example:

```py
from enum import Enum


class OneObject:
    pass

class TwoObject:
    pass

class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE: 1
    TWO: 2
```

I am looking to have something like this:

```py
from typing import TypedDict


class CustomDict(TypedDict):
    MyEnum.ONE: list[OneObject]
    MyEnum.TWO: list[TwoObject]
```

However, I am getting `Non-self attribute could not be type hinted` and it doesn't really work. What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **not compatible** with the [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) specification as laid out in [PEP 589](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#specification). Let me quote: (emphasis mine)

> A TypedDict type represents dictionary objects with a specific set of **string keys**, and with specific value types for each valid key.

So using arbitrary enum members for defining `TypedDict` keys is invalid.

While `TypedDict` does also support an [alternative, functional definition syntax](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#alternative-syntax) and you *could* theoretically make your enum have the `str` [data type](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#restricted-enum-subclassing) by doing `class MyEnum(str, Enum): ...`, you would still *probably* not be able to define a `TypedDict` with those enum members in a way that your type checker understands.

That is because only **actual string literals** are officially accepted as keys as mentioned in the section on the [Use of Final Values and Literal Types](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#use-of-final-values-and-literal-types). Quote: (again, emphasis mine)

> Type checkers are only expected to support **actual string literals**, not final names or literal types, **for specifying keys** in a TypedDict type definition. [...] The motivation for this is to make type declarations self-contained, and to simplify the implementation of type checkers.

In other words, whether something like the following is supported depends entirely on any given type checker:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import TypedDict


class OneObject:
    pass


class TwoObject:
    pass


class MyEnum(str, Enum):
    ONE = "1"
    TWO = "2"


CustomDict = TypedDict(
    "CustomDict",
    {MyEnum.ONE: list[OneObject], MyEnum.TWO: list[TwoObject]}
)
```

Mypy (currently) does not and gives the output: `error: Invalid TypedDict() field name`. (By the way, I tested it with [`Final`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Final) variables as keys and those are also rejected.)

So depending on what your use case is, you will probably have to bite the bullet and explicitly type out the enum/key names again or just not use an enum for that in the first place, as suggested by [@artem in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76399763/19770795).

Comment: That makes sense then why it wouldn't work. It's unfortunate as I do need them to be integers. I will make do without the completion for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your motivation for using Enum is, but I can suggest a solution without Enum. I personally think that it does not add any value in this case.

```py
class OneObject:
    pass


class TwoObject:
    pass


class CustomDict(TypedDict):
    ONE: list[OneObject]
    TWO: list[TwoObject]


test: CustomDict = {"ONE": [OneObject()], "TWO": [TwoObject()]}
```